# Clang-Tidy not found after installed

Tags: cmake, clion, clang-tidy

After I installed the CLion. I used `brew install llvm@7` and installed successfully.

The CMake options is set as

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DLLVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@/7.0.1/lib/cmake/llvm/
..
```

And the path for Clang-Tidy is also correct.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@7/7.0.1/bin/clang-tidy
```

[image: the path of Clang-Tidy]

However it still occurs with error 'Clang-Tidy not found'

`if(NOT CLANG_TIDY_EXECUTABLE)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "clang-tidy not found")
endif()`

[image: project]

So what could be the reason that Clang-Tidy is not available? I need to use this because Clang-tidy is the linter that used in my course. (I'm new with CLion and CMake)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that clang-tidy was installed in a standard location searched by `find_program()`?  Try setting `CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH` or `CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH`.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/find_program.html